# Как правильно использовать hashlib.shake_256()?

Tags: python, хеширование

Пытаюсь закодировать текст из файла с помощью алгоритма shake 256, но возникает ошибка. Как можно исправить?
Ошибка:

```
  File "C:\Users\я\Downloads\dhfueue.py", line 5, in <module>
    sha = hashlib.shake_256(my_string).hexdigest()
TypeError: hexdigest() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Код:

```
import hashlib
str="C:\\Users\\я\\Desktop\\1.txt"
my_file = open(str,'rb')
my_string = my_file.read()
sha = hashlib.shake_256(my_string).hexdigest()
print(sha)
```

Comment: Для начала просто необходимо прочитать текст ошибки. Из него понятно как можно исправить.

Comment: @Эникейщик в этом  и проблема, не знаю как исправить, какой аргумент нужно передавать, при алгоритме sha256 всё работает, зачем сразу минусовать вопрос, я думаю у вас тоже по началу были ошибки, спасибо.

Comment: Разумеется были и продолжают быть. Я читаю документацию и исправляю. Из вашего вопроса непонятно, читали ли вы вообще текст ошибки и пытались ли самостоятельно найти решение.

Comment: Минус, кстати, за бессмысленный заголовок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно указать размер байтового объекта, функция hexdigest(255) принимает этот размер, который находится в диапазоне от 0 до 255

```
sha = hashlib.shake_256(my_string).hexdigest(255)
```